# Send keys to page without an input element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

On a web page that has a `keypress` event listener running I want to be able to test sending keystrokes.  But the page doesn't have an input element, and calling

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")).SendKeys("abc");
```

Throws an error about needing the element to be editable to accept key strokes (against Chrome).

Is there any way to generate the keystrokes so the page sees them without injecting a dummy input element?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I haven't tested it but would you mind give `Actions.SendKeys` a try?

Example is in C#:

```c#
// without an element
new Actions(driver).SendKeys("abc").Perform();

// send keys to body
new Actions(driver).SendKeys(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")), "abc").Perform();
```

Comment: Thanks -- that worked great.  For anyone else looking Actions is in the OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions namespace